# My WordPress plugin cannot load my JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm making a WordPress plugin which uses Google maps JavaScript API to show multiple locations in a map. For this reason it needs to have javascript in the plugin's frontend for the map to work.

To make javascript work with my plugin, at first I included my PHP code in a WordPress page using the plugin "Insert PHP" and my Javascript and CSS in the same page using the plugin "Scripts 'n Styles". Now, it's obvious that this approach isn't correct because i can't upload my plugin to the WordPress directory this way and ask the users to install all these plugins.

So I transfered my PHP code to my plugin's main PHP file and the PHP code works great. However, trying to load my external JS file `DynamicMap.js` and also my external CSS file `DynamicMap.css` doesn't work at at all. Now I don't know about the CSS but I know that the JS file doesn't load at all because I have an `alert` command at the first line of the JS file which should indicate that the file was loaded succesfully. So what could be the issue here?

Here is the relevant code in my plugin's main PHP file:
(Note that I use the `add_shortcode` function to show the plugin's frontend elements in any page or post I add the shortcode to.)

```
<?php 


// register jquery and style on initialization
add_action('init', 'register_script');

function register_script()
{
  wp_register_script( 'custom_jquery', plugins_url('DynamicMap.js', __FILE__), array('jquery') );

  wp_register_style( 'new_style', plugins_url('DynamicMap.css', __FILE__), false, '1.0.0', 'all');
}

// use the registered jquery and style above
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_style');

function enqueue_style()
{
  wp_enqueue_script('custom_jquery');

  wp_enqueue_style( 'new_style' );
} 



function RenderPluginFrontend()
{

  //PHP code to connect to the database.

  //PHP code that allows the user to select a city and area from the database, to show the selected area's stores on the map.

}

add_shortcode('DMOSL', 'RenderPluginFrontend');


function oscimp_admin()
{
  include('map_of_resellers_admin.php');
}

function mapofresellers_admin_actions()
{
  add_options_page("Map of Resellers", "Map of Resellers", "read", "Map of Resellers", "oscimp_admin");
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'mapofresellers_admin_actions');


?>
```

I think that there is no need to include the code in my JS file because like I said I have an `alert` command at the very first line of the file and it doesn't appear at all in the browser. Thanks in advance for any help.

**Update:** Turns out that my issue wasn't in my code itself, but due to the fact that the changes I was making to my external JS file didn't apply unless i cleared my browser's cache.

See my relevant question here: [The changes I make to an external JS file of my WP plugin are only applied after I clear my browser's cache](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/301418/the-changes-i-make-to-an-external-js-file-of-my-wp-plugin-are-only-applied-after/301421?noredirect=1#comment445715_301421).

When I initially created the JS file it didn't have any `alert` commands to let me know that it loaded successfully but the Google map wasn't showing due to an error in my CSS file. When I later added `alert` commands to debug it, the `alert` commands weren't showing because my browser used the initial cached version of my JS file, so I was fooled into thinking that it wasn't loaded. So problem solved and thanks to all the people that answered my questions.

Comment: First, have you read up on including scripts in WP? You should not registering on the `init` action, but just enqueue them on the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action.  Second, have you `var_dump`-ed the location of your script path? `var_dump( plugins_url('DynamicMap.js', __FILE__) )`?  Is that script in the "root" folder of the plugin? Lastly, have you done "view source" in your browser? Do the URL's show up for your files? Are ANY of your PHP functions running?

Comment: @cale_b Thanks for the helpful comment. 1) I have read some articles online and this is the code I came up with. Question: if I don't register the scripts first, how will WP know the path of the script before enqueuing it? 2) The `var_dumb` doesn't include the `htdocs` folder after the base URL. e.g. the correct url is `http://codescapes.byethost3.com/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/Map_of_resellers/DynamicMap.js` while the var_dumb prints `http://codescapes.byethost3.com/wp-content/plugins/Map_of_resellers/DynamicMap.js`. 3) Yes. 4) None of my files show up in the "view source".(I ran out of chars)

Comment: Make sure your settings are correct in Wordpress admin -> settings -> general. If you're not running wordpress in the root directory, you may have to adjust these. (In your case, you might have to add /htdocs to the WordPress URL.) Also, you don't need to call the register functions because if you try to enqueue a script that isn't registered, the enqueue function will register it for you. Look up wp_enqueue_script at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/ to read about it's arguments

Comment: @Myles I tried adding `/htdocs` to the WordPress URL and it didn't work. I also tried inserting the exact URL of my script to the `wp_register_script` function and this didn't work either. My script still doesn't load.